# C# Convert Double to a string from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

On my button click I am getting the following error when the value being replaced is only a number (e.g. `40`) and it is being replaced by a string (e.g. `AB123`).

> System.Exception: AB123 is not a valid value for Double. --->
>
> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)

Button Click:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (!RowIsEmpty(i))
            {
                dataGridView1[3, i].Value = Combo.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried implicitly converting this like so:

```
dataGridView1[3, i].Value.ToString() = Combo.Text;
```

But that doesn't work, I have also tried calling it as a string like so:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (!RowIsEmpty(i))
            {
                string DGVS = dataGridView1[3, i].Value.ToString();
                DGVS =  Combo.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

But that doesn't give an error but doesn't actually do anything.

Data is loaded in from an excel file.

Example

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
AAA   BBB   40
```

ComboBox:

```
ABC123
```

Comment: What is returning in `datagridView1[3, i].Value`?

Comment: it loads in a number value e.g. `40`

Comment: The DGV is pretty sure that Column[3] contains `double` values. You could try to presuade it otherwise, changing the ValueType of the DataSource (if possible and convenient). If not possible, you have to adapt. But, you should know what kind of data that Column/Field should contain.

Comment: @Jimi How would I do that

Comment: Is column 3 in DGV is of type `double`?

Comment: It depends. What is the DGV DataSource? Did you set the DataTypes explicitly? Do you need to update a source of data that is expecting `double` values? BTW, the title of this question is misleading. It's not clear what you want to convert to or from. The title says the opposite of what it seems you're trying to do.

Comment: @Jimi true, that's why I got a bit confused too...

Comment: Also, you can try with Convert.ToDouble()

Comment: But are you actually referring to `Column[2] (the third column) instead of `Column[3]` (the fourth column)? Do you need to break down `ABC123` and distribute it among columns? Is there a reason why you're trying to assign a string to a column that holds `double` values? What are you going to do with it then? Do you have to send this data back to Excel? Otherwise store it somewhere? Does the column's data type matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this (maybe not the best way but it works) by removing and re adding the column after the load into the datagridview but before the update of the combobox value into the rows.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column3New = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    Column3New.Name = "Column3";
    Column3New.HeaderText = "Column3";
    dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(3, Column3New);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        if (!RowIsEmpty(i))
        {
            dataGridView1[3, i].Value = Combo.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I guess I found the solution:

```
double price;
bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out price);
if (isDouble)
{
     Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
     dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = textBox1.Text;
}
else
{
     dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Basically, first check if the textbox is double or not. If is double, convert to double and add it to DGV. If it's string, just add the string into DGV.

Tests:

```
TextBox1.Text = AAA; //worked
TextBox1.Text = BBB; //worked
TextBox1.Text = 40; //worked
TextBox1.Text = 40.00; //worked
TextBox1.Text = 42,20; //worked
```